# how to cd into a thumb drive from terminal ( Mac OSX )

Tags: mac, macos, bash, terminal

How do i change into the directory of my thumbdrive? I've been poking around and see that this command, "diskutil list", lists all my local disks. That produces this..

```
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:~ davidadams$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            249.7 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk3
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 THUMBDRIVE              4.0 GB     disk3s1
```

now i see that my thumbdrive is showing up in /dev/disk3 but i can't get to it. I can cd into /dev but thats as far as i can get.

"cd /dev/disk3/THUMBDRIVE" tells me "-bash: cd: /dev/disk3/THUMBDRIVE: Not a directory"

any help would be great.

Comment: linux or mac? your prompt says mac, so I changed the tags

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
# cd /Volumes && ls
```

It will show you the directory location of all mounted volumes. Then just cd into the drive you want.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. So simple but works.

Answer (score 12):

Mac OS X mounts drives automatically under /Volumes.

```
mress:10042 Z$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS mress HD                999.9 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS mress™                  1.0 TB     disk1s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Development             512.2 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Media                   987.7 GB   disk2s3
mress:10043 Z$ ls /Volumes
Development/ Media/       mress HD@    mress™/
```

You'll notice the directories match the `NAME` column.

Answer (score 9):

In Terminal, if you

```
ls /Volumes
```

you'll see all of your drives. You can then cd to one of them (or just cd directly - no need to list the volumes first). For example:

```
cd /Volumes/My\ Other\ Drive
```

Spaces are replaced by '\ '. Or you can put the whole thing in quotes:

```
cd /Volumes/"My Other Drive"
```

If the drive name has no spaces, then you'd just use the name:

```
cd /Volumes/MyOtherDrive
```

Answer (score 2):

If you drag and drop the icon corresponding to the volume on the USB drive from the Desktop (or Finder) into the Terminal window, it will automatically paste the path where that volume is mounted.  This will most likely be a path in `/Volumes`.

Answer (score 0):

ypuou have to mount it first.

```
#mkdir /media/myusbstick
#mount /dev/disk3 /media/myusbstick
# cd /media/myusbstick
```

make a directory, then mount then cd into it

You need to be root to do this, there are ways to set it up so users can mount like common GUI's do, but that is beyond me

EDIT: sorry you tagged your post with linux,?? but you have a mac? This is for linux, if you were curious